# Problem related to null safety: A nullable expression can't be used as a condition

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I encountered this error regarding null safety and I could not solve it

```
HomeModel? homeModel;

  Map<int, bool> favorites = {};

  void getHomeData() {
    emit(ShopLoadingHomeDataState());

    DioHelper.getData(
      url: HOME,
      token: token,
    ).then((value) {
      homeModel = HomeModel.fromJson(value?.data);

      printFullText(homeModel!.data!.banners[0].image!);
      print(homeModel?.status);
      
      homeModel!.data!.products.forEach((element) {
        favorites.addAll({
          element.id! : element.inFavorites!,
        });
      });

      emit(ShopSuccessHomeDataState());
    });
```

Here, an error occurs

```
backgroundColor: ShopCubit.get(context).favorites[model.id] ? defaultColor : Colors.grey ,
```

And say :

> "A nullable expression can't be used as a condition.
> Try checking that the value isn't 'null' before using it as a condition."

And:

> "Error: A value of type 'bool?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'bool' because 'bool?' is nullable and 'bool' isn't"

please help me

Comment: ShopCubit.get(context).favorites[model.id] might return null at some point i guess, which is not boolean. You may fix it rewriting it as (ShopCubit.get(context).favorites[model.id] ?? false) ? ... : ...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the return of a map by a key, i.e. `map[key]`, will always have `null` attached to it because the value could not exist for the provided key.

To fix it default the value to something else if the `model.id` is not in the `favorites` map with the `??` operator like the following:

```dart
backgroundColor: ShopCubit.get(context).favorites[model.id] ?? false  // <- Here
  ? defaultColor 
  : Colors.grey,
```

Or, if the value exists for sure, just force it to be non-null with the postfix `!` operator. But take care as the value should exist otherwise an exception is thrown.

```dart
backgroundColor: ShopCubit.get(context).favorites[model.id]!  // <- Here
  ? defaultColor 
  : Colors.grey,
```

Answer (score 0):

The defaultColor must have been added like

```
Color? defaultColor = Colors.red;
```

make it

```
Color defaultColor = Colors.red;
```

remove the ? after Color

**Edit**

```
backgroundColor: ShopCubit.get(context).favorites[model.id] == null || ShopCubit.get(context).favorites[model.id] == true ? defaultColor : Colors.grey
```

Can also be written as

```
backgroundColor: ShopCubit.get(context).favorites[model.id] ?? true ? defaultColor : Colors.grey
```

Comment: I do it already
The error is not here, but in:
```
ShopCubit.get(context).favorites[model.id]
```